# Values Received from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I have received the data from the US Census API, but I'm not sure how to convert it into the value I want.

Each state is represented fro 01 to 56. Each number represents a different state. What I want to do is take the value the user entered and convert it into the state from the API.

One solution, which is more complicated and takes much much longer, is to use an if statement. If user enters in 02, state = "Alaska" etc etc. a 56 level nested loop. There has to be a way to get what I need from the API without doing this.
[Census API Example](http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/examples.html)
[List of Census Variables](http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/variables.html)

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="title">
        <h1>United States Population Search</h1>
        <hr/>
    </section>
    <section id="inputArea">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputBox" placeholder="Enter name of state." name="stateInput" autofocus required/>
            <input type="submit" class="searchButton"  value="Search"/>
            <hr/>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section class="searchResults">
        <div class="hiddenTemplates">
            <dl class="stateInformation">
                <dt><u>Name of State:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="stateName"></dd>
                <dt><u>Population Amount:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="statePopulation"></dd>
                <dt><u>Population Density:</u></dt>
                    <dd class="statePopulationDensity"></dd>
            </dl>
            <div class="errorMessage">
                <p><b>Error Message: Something has gone wrong, try your search again.</b></p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
//This function fills in the result,
//in our results box, this will give us the name of the US State
var showStateInformation = function(stateSearch){

    //Puts the name of the state into the state name area
    var nameOfState = $('.stateName');
    nameOfState.text(stateSearch);
    //in our results box, this will give us the population for that state
    //based on the Census Data
    //var statePopAmount = result.find('.statePopulation');
    //statePopAmount.text(population);
    //in our results box, this will give us the population density for that state
    //based on the Census Data
    //var statePopDensity = result.find('.statePopulationDensity');
    //statePopDensity.text(populationDensity);

}

//The error message
var showError = function(error){
        var errorElem = $('.searchResults .errorMessage');
        var errorText = '<p>' + error + '</p>';
        errorElem.append(errorText);
}

//This function retrieves the said data
//http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/population-estimates-and-projections.html
//US, State, and PR Total Population and Components of Change

var getStateInformation = function(stateID){
    //the parameters that we need to pass in our request to the US CENSUS API
    var request = {
        "get": "STNAME",
        "DATE": "6",
        "for": "state:" + stateID,

        "key": 'I was told not to post my key code online'
    }

    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        url: "http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    //What the function should do if successful
    .done(function(){
        var stateSearch = $('#inputBox').val();
        showStateInformation(stateSearch);
    })

    //What the function should do if it fails
    .fail(function(jqXHR, error){
        var errorElem = showError(error);
    })


}

$(document).ready(function() {

    /*Clicking the Search Button*/
    $('.searchButton').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var stateID = $('#inputBox').val();
        getStateInformation(stateID);

    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a text input for the state, use a `<select>` dropdown. You can specify the exact value you want each state to map to in each `<option>` html and then map this to the API.

```
<select id="stateSelect">
    <option value="01">Alabama</option>
    ...
</select>
```

`$('#stateSelect').val()`

Comment: I'm going to do some investigating. I'm new to coding/api's etc, so this is something that I am building mostly for learning experience. Once I have learned more about <select> I'll come back and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Good luck! This is absolutely the best approach. With a text input your users could mistype or assume they should abbreviate with 'CA' for California. There is no good way to properly match all of that. The <select> will give you the right value.

Comment: Well, each value, 02 represents Alaska for example, corresponds to a certain population or population density. After I get the state park working, I'm going to try to grab the population and population density from the Census Bureau API. Are you sure this is the best approach with that thought in mind? Keep in mind, I new to this stuff haha I am a newb

Comment: Sorry, were you going to have the user type "02" or "Alaska"? Which are you sending to the server? Do you already have a full list of what ID goes with what State?

Comment: Thank you for all of your help Compton. As of right now, the user types in a value, such as 02, 03, etc. This gets sent to the server. I want the return value to be a state name. If I use your drop down method, that's fine, but will this work if my ultimate end goal is to get the population and population density for each state fro the US Census API? [List of state id values](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/ansi_statetables.html) It's the second drop down.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Using the <select> the user can choose a state using its actual name and the code I provided will retrieve the correct ID to send to the server. :)

Comment: Okay, I will experiment with this and let you know how it goes by end of day tomorrow

Comment: I like the drop down, it looks amazing and was much better than just putting in a number like I had previously. I am still having issues communicating with the server, but I definitely like this drop down. I am testing something with this and will follow up sometime tomorrow.

Comment: I fixed the issue I was having. Thank you so much Comptonburger!